# Significance of entering both title and name while creating a form

Tags: formsflow.ai, formsflow

While creating a new form,do we need to enter both title and name for the form?may i know why it is mandatory to enter both or what is the difference between Form title and name?
One more thing i noticed is like i can enter same title for multiple forms and is not unique.

Answer (score 1):

The way it was explained to me, and how I have used them, is that the Title is the name of the form, how it is identified to yourself and others.  The Name is the roll that it plays.  So you might title the form MyDataForm1, but if the form is for the process of payroll analysis, it's name would be PayRollAnalysis1.

I hope I did not misunderstand the nature of the question, but that is how I interpret the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But my doubt is what should be displayed to user as form name?title or name? since title is not unique ,name should be displayed no?